# My maven project can't found resources he found earlier but anymore

Tags: java, maven

I'm having troubles making my maven project work.
It can't found my images in the src/main/resources folder but it worked yesterday...
I added a maven module since then named Plugins [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJqad.png)
My project structure look like this : [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDKlq.png)
And the error tag in this kind of code (I debugged to see where it happens): [Problematic code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhiIb.png)
If you can tell me what I'm doing wrong, cause i'm losing my mind here.
Thank you guys !

Comment: You have to use `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/path/to/image");`and no access via `File` will work...

Comment: Please replace screenshots of error and the problematic code with text.

Answer (score 0):

It is better for you loading Images with IO if you don’t have some specific reason why to not use it.

If you show more code I will help you more, but try doing this:

```
img = ImageIO.read(new File("path/to/image"));
this.backgroundImage = new BackgroundImage(img);
```